# Showing the total amount in one line (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find out how to show the total value in a table (item*quantity) of all the items in one line. The code below shows the total of every single item on one line each, not the total value of all of them. How can this be done?

I guess I should use a subquery, but not how to design it.

Thanks in advance

```
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(8,0),ROUND((quantity*price),2)) AS Total
FROM Item
```

EDIT: By mistage I included ITEMNAME, that shall NOT be a part of the result!

The table is designed as follows:

```
ITEMNAME   QUANTITY   PRICE
Table      20         100
Chair      30         50
and so on
```

The result is as follows:

```
ITEMNAME   TOTAL
Table      2000
Chair      1500
```

I want it this way:

```
TOTAL
3500
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample output and to make your column names and text description match. (You say `(item*quantity)` in your text, but reference `(quantity*price)` in your SQL. It's easier to answer if your question stays consistent in terminology.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM (quantity*price) AS Total
FROM Item
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Itemname, CONVERT(Decimal(8,0),ROUND((SUM(quantity*price)),2)) AS Total
FROM Item
GROUP BY Itemname
```

You need to include the `GROUP BY` if you want to include additional columns.

If you just want the Total, then

```
SELECT SUM(quantity*price) AS Total
FROM Item
```

If you want the sum of all records then you can do the following, this will get the sum of all rows:

```
SELECT SUM(T.Total)
FROM 
(
    select sum(quantity*price) as total
    from Item
) T
```

If you want to add the convert:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Decimal(8,0),ROUND(SUM(T.Total)),2)) 
FROM 
(
    select sum(quantity*price) as total
    from Item
) T
```

Comment: He does not need group by clause, this query will return sum for each unique itemname

Comment: I've actually tried that, but by some strange reason it generates the same result. :/

Comment: Use query provided by @list. Also you can use window (row) function, if you db provider support it

Comment: @Umar he does need the group by if you want to include Itemname in the Select statement.

Comment: @JasonCraig if you run this query with out the Convert, you are not returning the sum()?

Comment: This mean, that question is incorrect, cause it's not clear what he want to see in itemname. It's not summ of all rows

Comment: @Umar that is probably true, but my answer was based off of the OP which included the Itemname in the select list